# MySQL: How to use JSON_ARRAY in WHERE..IN clause?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-json

Is there a way to use the `JSON_ARRAY` in `WHERE..IN` clause?

For example, the following is the `JSON_ARRAY`.

```
SET @codes := JSON_ARRAY('CA' , 'NY' , 'TX');
```

And I need to do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `state` WHERE `code` IN (@codes);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mysql version higher than 8.0 you can try to use [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), let your JSON array to data row then do `in` logic.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE `state`  (
   `code` VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO `state` VALUES ('C1');
INSERT INTO `state` VALUES ('CA');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SET @codes := JSON_ARRAY('CA' , 'NY' , 'TX');

SELECT * 
FROM `state` 
WHERE `code` IN (
     SELECT val
     FROM JSON_TABLE(
      @codes,
      "$[*]"
      COLUMNS(
       val varchar(50) PATH "$"
      )
   ) data
);

| code |
| ---- |
| CA   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/44hyBAboDj828xdLpWb3Y5/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search), checking for a non-`NULL` result to see if the `code` value is contained in `@codes`:

```
SET @codes := JSON_ARRAY('CA' , 'NY' , 'TX');
SELECT code, JSON_SEARCH(@codes, 'one', code) IS NOT NULL AS found
FROM state;
```

Output (for my demo)

```
code    found
CA      1
NY      1
TX      1
AK      0
WA      0
```

Or, if you just want a list of `code` within `@codes`:

```
SELECT code
FROM state
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(@codes, 'one', code) IS NOT NULL
```

Output

```
code
CA
NY
TX
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k8t8frrHLmjL1XNtgXthMs/2)